# How can I get 4 Keycards?

Tags: risk-of-rain

I only got 3 yellow crates which contain keycards, and there is a bit of info on the game's wiki that says they may drop from certain enemies, but so far I have not been lucky enough. Which enemies should I farm for keycards? How does the drop chance change when the difficulty level is maxed out?

Comment: Ended up clearing the whole level for an hour and the keycard didn't drop :( Game difficulty was Drizzle though so maybe that has an effect. In one of the other playthroughs I noticed a keycard dropped at the start of the level from one of the monsters but still I could only get a total of 3 then (2 more from crates). So just 1 drop from enemies in my experience. Maybe that's a limitation or maybe one of the enemies that was supposed to drop a keycard on death got pushed out of the level by one of my attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Keycards can definitely drop from multiple enemies.
I am not exactly sure which ones, but I think the Vagrant versions that spawn there, as well as blighted enemies. Maybe even more.

The dropchances are increased the higher the difficulty is. So playing on monsoon and having taken a long time should help the drop rate. Also collecting the 56 Leaf Clover should help you, since it increases item drops from champions.

And regarding your last question: the difficulty never maxes out. The bar can only get so full but the difficulty will continue to rise. It only rises at different speeds depending on the initial difficulty you picked.